# Checkbox component cannot trigger the correct input on next page

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts, struts-1

In this JSP file I want to display the checkbox on the next page, for example if C1 is chosen then only C1 should be displayed and if C2 is chosen then C2  is displayed. If both are selected then both should be displayed, all I am getting are both of the values on the next page regardless of the checkbox being selected or not.

page1.jsp:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
    
            <html:checkbox property="prcCode1Checkbox" styleId="prccode1" value="C1" ></html:checkbox>
            <span class="mainText"> <bean:message key="C1_option" /></span>
            <html:checkbox property="prcCode2Checkbox" styleId="prccode2" value="C2"></html:checkbox>
            <span class="mainText"> <bean:message key="C2_option" /></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

page2.jsp:

```
<table>
    <div class="app_row">
        <div class="field_label3">
            <bean:message key="code_of_prc_driving_licence" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <bean:write name="appSubmitForm" property="prcCode1Checkbox"  />
        </div>
        <div>
        <bean:write name="appSubmitForm" property="prcCode2Checkbox"  />  
        </div>
                                                        
        </div>
        </table>
```

This is the getter and setter for this application.
ApplicationSubmit.java:

```
public String getPrcCode1Checkbox() {
        return prcCode1Checkbox;
    }
    public void setPrcCode1Checkbox(String prcCode1Checkbox) {
        this.prcCode1Checkbox = prcCode1Checkbox;
    }
    public String getPrcCode2Checkbox() {
        return prcCode2Checkbox;
    }
    public void setPrcCode2Checkbox(String prcCode2Checkbox) {
        this.prcCode2Checkbox = prcCode2Checkbox;
    }
```

This is the output of the result regardless of whether I chose the checkbox or not.